# how can i create a list using textview with proper layout instead of ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i want two textview beside each other and i want KEY_TITLE and KEY_CDATE that is title and date into my textview from the database.I have done this using ListView by using android default layout but i want to create my own layout which should contain Two TextView and One checkbox in a single line(beside each other) .So can anyone tell me how to do this using database?
Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/myyellow"
>

<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code for to fill the list

```
private void fillData() {  
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();  
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE,NotesDbAdapter.KEY_CDATE};

    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Comment: Or instead of using listview how can show this in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

the above tutorial should help you do what you want, it's a guide to create a custom list view. What I would do is to make a class, and create instances for each row in your database, and then use the custom layout to display the data in the ListView. There should be minimal differences from setting it up with images and checkboxes.

Comment: i have seen this but as i am a beginner its quite difficult to understand

Comment: Where do you get stuck in the guide?
I think this is actually easier to understand. http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: i dont know how to create a custom layout for each row in listview

Comment: I always start out by creating a XML layout for the row in the listview, imagine you had a screen where you only wanted to show the data for a single row. After that you need to create an adapter the "WeatherAdapter.java" in the guide in the comment.